# what should be the return type of method that returning xml string?

Tags: c#, xml

I have data access method that retrieves xml from database and returns back to business layer.  What should be the return type?  Should I simply return them as a string?  What is the best practice when returning xml from one layer to another?

I will be returning that xml back to client or may be convert them to json based on client request.

Comment: I think you should parse the XML and return your own defined objects.

Comment: +1 for returning your own type. Sounds like you should have an IParser, XmlParsers and JsonParser, along with an IDataReturn, XmlDataRetrun and JsonDataReturn. You can pass an IParser into your data retreival method, and it can call Parse() on the IParser to get an IDataReturn and return that back up to the client code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd argue that this decision depends on what use cases should cover your method.

When I'd return a string:

- Code invoking your method isn't going to manipulate the result as XML, *so why wasting CPU and memory loading a complex object like XmlDocument or XDocument, or whatever? just return a string!*
- Returned XML is a serialized object. You're going to parse this XML string into an actual .NET object.

When I'd return an XML object like `XDocument` or `XmlDocument`:

- Code invoking your method is going to manipulate the result as XML. This includes adding new nodes, attributes, or just read some elements or attributes in your XML.
- Code invoking your method uses some .NET base class library or third-party library that needs an XML object as argument.

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention the part of "JSON or XML" depending on client request.

*Obviously*, if your client needs XML, just return your data as XML, and if your client needs JSON, just return your data as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I would get it from the database as a string, and then Parse to XML using XElement.Parse(XML_STING); . If you need to parse to JSON instead, you can you a JSON parser without changing how it gets it from the DB.

Comment: thanks.  but my question is that should i return as a string from data access layer to business layer or as as a xml object?

Comment: as a string i think. then you can be more flexible if your future needs change as to what you need to do with the data.

Comment: If he should return String, then why `XElement.Parse(XML_STING);`?!!

Comment: If the parse fails b/c of malformed XML or other issues, at least he will still have the string of data. If getting XML (not a string) for the DB, an error would be raised in the data retrieval, and he would not get access to the data at all.